# Session Storage Shopping Cart

Tags: javascript

I would like to add items to my shopping cart and display them in a list.
My code doesn't seem to be working
Here's the git hub link:
[GitHub](https://github.com/camilleHendricks/shoppingcar-)

```js
var cart = {};
function addToCart(product){
 var productName = product.getAttribute("data-name");
 var price = product.getAttribute("data-price");

 cart[productName] = price;
 alert(productName + " successfully added to cart");


 console.log(cart);
 sessionStorage.setItem("myCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function getCart(){
 var test = sessionStorage.getItem("myCart");
 console.log(JSON.parse(test));
}

function clearCart(){
 sessionStorage.removeItem("myCart");
}

function display(){
 var cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("myCart"));

 var content='';
 for (var key in cart) {
  var name = key; //B
  var price = cart[key];  //15
   content += '<tr><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+price+'</td></tr>';
 }

 document.getElementById("cartTable").innerHTML = content;

}
```

```html
<h1>My Cart</h1>

 <table id="cartTable">
  <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Price</td>
  </tr>


 </table>
  
  <!-- Code from index.html -->
  <button id="prodA" data-name="A" data-price="10" onclick="addToCart(this)">Add to cart</button>
  <!-- end of code -->

 <button id="tCart" onclick="display()">View</button>


<button id="getCart" onclick="getCart()" ><a href="cart.html">View Cart</a></button>
```

Comment: Provide the faulty code here as well.

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: It is working for me. I added only clearing `cart` variable in `clearCart()`. I shared example on https://jsfiddle.net/cichy380/2jcwdtf1/ because JSFiddle support HTML Storage.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you change the cart from an object to an array, and then push products directly into the cart.

Once you do this, change "display()" function to be like this:

```
function display() {
    var cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("myCart"));
    var content = document.getElementById("cartTable");

    content.innerHTML = cart.map(product => {
        return '<tr><td>' + product.name + '</td><td>' + product.price + '</td></tr>';
    }).join('');
}
```